# Is it possible to query the MacBook Pro sudden motion sensor via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, motion-detection

Is it possible to query the sudden motion sensor via JavaScript in the browser?

Comment: Are there more sensors than the one in the hard drive?

Comment: no, it's the Hard drive one. I don't think javascript is able to manipulate such stuff

Comment: Never heard, desktop browsers were able to provide such things. One may write plugin for a browser, which will access it via some system calls and expose into javascript.